# Expected Time for LookUpSkipList

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, runtime-analysis, lists

A skip list

[image: skip list example]

Let C(k) = the expected length of the path that raises k levels backwards.

Thus C(0) = 0

For any node P in the path, with k levels higher to go, there are two cases:

1. P is a node of level i and proceeds backwards to a node of at least level i and still k levels to go
2. P is a node at a level higher than i and must yet rise (k-1) levels

Each of these two cases has a probability of 0.5
[image: analysis]

Why C(k) = 2k and how to interpret this formula? Is the analysis formula in the figure right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence can be solved as:
$$
\begin{align}
C(k) &= \frac{1 + C(k)}{2} + \frac{1 + C(k-1)}{2}\\
2 \cdot C(k) &= 1 + C(k) + 1 + C(k-1)\\
C(k) &= 1 + 1 + C(k-1)\\
C(k) &= 2 + C(k-1)\\
\end{align}
$$
Then this can clearly be expanded to a summation:
$$
\begin{align}
C(k) &= 2 + C(k-1)\\
&= 2 + 2 + C(k - 2)\\
&= 2 + 2 + 2 + C(k - 3)\\
& \dots\\
&= 2 + 2 + \dots + C(1)\\
&= 2k\\
\end{align}
$$

I haven't done much investigation into skip lists, but the math you've shown checks out. ✓

**EDIT**

The reason $C(k)$ appears in the left and right side of the equation, which seems *concerning*, is because of the Skip List structure. Take this procedure ([source](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/skiplists.pdf)) to $find(86)$:

[image: Skip List]

Now let's consider the *reverse* of this path. Notice we *always* move up if we can. So for any node in the *reverse* path, we can either (1) move up or (2) move left:

1. We move up. Now we have $C(k-1)$ more levels up to go: $$1 + C(k - 1)$$
2. We move left. We have made **no** progress upwards, therefore we still have $C(k)$ more levels up to go: $$1 + C(k)$$

For a randomized skip list, either of these scenarios occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. This is how we get the final recurrence:

$$C(k) = \frac{1 + C(k)}{2} + \frac{1 + C(k-1)}{2}$$

Comment: C(k) = 2k 
C(k) = the expected length of the path that raises k levels backward
The length is only a function of level k. When I see the proof process at the first time, I cannot understand why $$ C(k) $$ in the left hand side and that in the right hand side is same in the equation $$ C(k) = \frac{1 + C(k)}{2} + \frac{1 + C(k-1)}{2} $$ .  I think the expected length of the path is different anyway.

Comment: @skytreekirei, I've edited my answer to address why $C(k)$ can be on the left and right side of the recurrence. I hope this helps.